Replace an empty value with nan in dataframe
I have a dataframe with empty values in some rows like this:
ID       Date     Price  Curr
A        Jan 21    (10,0)     USD
B        Aug 8     (10,0)     USD
C        Sep 29    (10,0)     USD
settle   Aug 24    (   ,)

where the last row has 2 empty values in Price and Curr columns.
How can I either replace the empty values with nan so I can dropna() or drop the rows that contain empty values to get a dataframe like:
ID       Date     Price  Curr
A        Jan 21    (10,0)     USD
B        Aug 8     (10,0)     USD
C        Sep 29    (10,0)     USD

sample:
data = {
    "ID": ["A", "B", "C", "settle"],
    "Date": ["Jan 21", "Aug 8", "Sep 29", "Aug 24"],
    "Price": [(10,0), (10,0), (10,0), ()],
    "Curr": ["USD", "USD", "USD", ""]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


Provide the code(like pd.DataFrame(data)) to create the input dataframe.

updated for you @PandaKim

{  "name": "SyntaxError",  "message": "invalid syntax (2584679549.py, line 4)",  "stack": "  Cell In[4], line 4     \"Price\": [(10,0), (10,0), (10,0), (   ,)],                                           ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax " } -- it does not create the dataframe!

To drop the rows that are empty, you can try something like this:
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "ID": ["A", "B", "C", "settle"],
    "Date": ["Jan 21", "Aug 8", "Sep 29", "Aug 24"],
    "Price": [(10, 0), (10, 0), (10, 0), ()],
    "Curr": ["USD", "USD", "USD", ""]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Filter out rows where Price is an empty tuple
df = df[df['Price'].apply(lambda x: len(x) > 0)]

# Convert the 'Price' tuples to floats by taking the first element of each tuple
df['Price'] = df['Price'].apply(lambda x: float(x[0]))

print(df)
print(df.dtypes)

# Output
  ID    Date  Price Curr
0  A  Jan 21   10.0  USD
1  B   Aug 8   10.0  USD
2  C  Sep 29   10.0  USD

ID        object
Date      object
Price    float64
Curr      object
dtype: object


@BigBen I updated it, they are tuples.

the condition filters out rows from df that contain any empty values and keeps only the rows where that are non-empty.

Is there a way to achieve this without converting to string type? I need the values to be floats

Updated my answer.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You can filter rows if not empty tuples or empty values exist in any column :
out = df[df[['Price','Curr']].astype(bool).all(axis=1)]
print (out)
  ID    Date    Price Curr
0  A  Jan 21  (10, 0)  USD
1  B   Aug 8  (10, 0)  USD
2  C  Sep 29  (10, 0)  USD

Also is possible set missing values:
out = df.where(df.astype(bool)).dropna()
print (out)
  ID    Date    Price Curr
0  A  Jan 21  (10, 0)  USD
1  B   Aug 8  (10, 0)  USD
2  C  Sep 29  (10, 0)  USD

Better solution is filter only columns with strings and tuples with DataFrame.select_dtypes and for test empty strings cast values to boolean:
data = {
    "ID": ["A", "B", "C", "settle"],
    "Date": ["Jan 21", "Aug 8", "Sep 29", "Aug 24"],
    "Price": [(10,0), (10,0), (10,0), (),],
    "Curr": ["USD", "USD", "USD", ""],
    'Val':[1,2,5,6]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

out = df[df.select_dtypes('object').astype(bool).all(axis=1)]
print (out)
0  A  Jan 21  (10, 0)  USD    1
1  B   Aug 8  (10, 0)  USD    2
2  C  Sep 29  (10, 0)  USD    5

How it working:
print (df.select_dtypes('object'))
       ID    Date    Price Curr
0       A  Jan 21  (10, 0)  USD
1       B   Aug 8  (10, 0)  USD
2       C  Sep 29  (10, 0)  USD
3  settle  Aug 24       ()    

print (df.select_dtypes('object').astype(bool))
     ID  Date  Price   Curr
0  True  True   True   True
1  True  True   True   True
2  True  True   True   True
3  True  True  False  False

print (df.select_dtypes('object').astype(bool).all(axis=1))
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool


Replace empty values with NaN:
df.replace({"": np.nan, "(   ,)": np.nan}, inplace=True)

Drop rows with NaN values:
df_clean = df.dropna()

Display the cleaned DataFrame:
print(df_clean)


if your data type is dataframe and has been stored in df variable:
conevert empty to  NaN
df.replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)

Drop rows with NaN values
df.dropna(inplace=True)

Reset index if needed
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

print(df)

